# Vb.net - array, database or sql

Tags: sql, arrays, database, vb.net, forms

I'm making my project for a-level computing and I reached a problem that im not sure how to solve. Im making something similar to a student information management system and I want a way to store a small list of students maybe 5 to 10 preferably in my program and make reference to them from all forms and so that if something is changed on one of the students maybe a piece of information, that these information is carried to the next form. My teacher has very little knowledge on programming and so im kind of stuck, i have no previous experience with databases or sql however if someone is willing to break it down ill be very grateful and ive got a good understanding of arrays. My deadline is the 10th of may so asap please, thanks
- kyle

Comment: if it is just 5-10 entries you could just use a static List<>() of students class to store your entries

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer simplicity I would stick to a CSV file or XML. I found a website which an end-to-end tutorial on how to create the XML and add items (students) to it using VB.net as according to your tag. You need only after to read them from the file, but might just as well add new:

http://vb.net-informations.com/xml/how-to-xml-in-vb.net.htm

I would stick with XML (or CSV as preffered) as it is a text file basically so you can see and make changes directly if needed.